# How to start logging web page errors

Tags: apache, logging, error-handling

I'm searching for a way to log http errors on Apache so I can track how to server goes and whose getting errors and for what kind of reason...

I would like to have a log file on my ubuntu server which, per line, indicate

```
YYYY.MM.DD Client-IP RECIEVED-403-ERROR /ON-THIS-PAGE
YYYY.MM.DD Client-IP RECIEVED-500-ERROR /ON-THIS-PAGE
```

no nescecery in this order but I guess you got the idea.

By this I will have information on:
1. how often my visitors recieve 500 error
2. Are there any cyber-kids or real hackers that want to find open directories (403 Forbidden)
3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [Access Logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html). The LogFormat directive you want should be:

```
LogFormat %{%Y.%m.%d}t %h %>s %r
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, apache already has lots of detailed logs in /var/log/apache folder. If you want to get detailed info as in the format you have mentioned above, then you will need to parse original logs and generate a report for example. Also, as these logs are text based and have a predefined structures, you can extract your required information.